# Best practice to check few rows and columns with Linq and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have one table in MSSQL:

```
int Id
int Col
int Row
```

I have a tilemap with some objects on it. 
Position of each object is **top left tile** (row and column number).
Object can occupy few tiles.

For example, i have an object with size **3х3**.
Position of this tile is **row 5** and **column 10**.

```
 IEnumerable<int> checkRows = Enumerable.Range(5, 3); // 5, 6, 7
 IEnumerable<int> checkCol = Enumerable.Range(10, 3); // 10, 11, 12
```

I need to check existing objects in this area before adding new one in DB:

```
5:10 | 5:11 | 5:12
6:10 | 6:11 | 6:12
7:10 | 7:11 | 7:12
```

If some object is in position 7:12, I will query DB too much before find it.

For one tile I've used:

```
 db.TileSet.Any(x => x.Col == col & x.Row == row)
```

What is the best solution or practice to avoid high load of CPU with Linq in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var tile in TilesToCheck)
{
    if(db.TileSet.Any(x => x.Col == tile.Col && x.Row == tile.Row))
    {
      // TODO: break the Save operation or whatever...
    }
}
```

Well, the way you're handling the check is OK. That's the standard way of doing this. `LINQ` and `Entity Framework` will generate an optimized query and send it to the database. So the heavy lifting will be on the DB side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for an exact coordinate, look in a range:

```
db.TileSet.Any(x =>
  x.Col >= col && x.Col <= col + 2 &&
  x.Row >= row && x.Row <= row + 2
)
```